# Change share permission of all sub-folder and file Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

When I change the [permission of Share folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbMs2.png) but [sub-folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ltlc.png) and file are still shared.

I want to change permission of all sub-folder at same time.

Comment: recursion is your friend

Comment: Can you please provide us what have you done so far? Are you using Drive API? Also, provide steps how you implement permission